# Is SMS Framework available for iphone to access sms?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For my requirement is need to access sms which we have in Inbox, is there any framework expose sms to access in iphone. please suggest me workaround, if it is not there direct framwwork.

sri

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) Class Reference.